# Helm-find-files on org link

Tags: org-mode, helm

When we call `helm-find-files` on an org link or path, helm is smart enough to autocomplete the path, making it easy for us to navigate from there. Unfortunately, if the link starts with [[file:./this/file/name.png]], then helm extended actions fail, because helm can't find a file that starts with "file:".

Does anyone know how I could advice helm-find-files to trim the "file:" part of a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can advice helm to strip the `file:` part:

```lisp
(advice-add 'helm-find-files-initial-input :filter-return
            (lambda (&optional input)
              (if (string-prefix-p "file:" input)
                  (replace-regexp-in-string "file:\\(.+\\)" "\\1" input)
                input)))
```

Comment: works perfectly!